# question about IDLE debugger in Python

Tags: python, list, debugging, python-idle, ellipsis

This is a simple question, is it possible to view an entire list in the locals box of the IDLE debugger? Because right now, if a list becomes too long, the debugger will put an ellipsis and not show the entire list. I also tried typing in the name of the list in the actual python shell, but nothing happened.

here is what i am seeing:`axyz        [[[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,...,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]]]`
and if i type axyz into the shell when the program is running, nothing happens.

Comment: Why not just `print axyz`? It should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dump out large quantities of debug information, import the logging module and invoke it like so:

```
import logging
logging.debug(str(axyz))
```

Python's [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) is tremendously versatile, and can be used for logging to any device in any format you desire.

Other severity levels can be logged (`logging.info()`, `logging.error()`, `logging.exception()`) and you can set the logging verbosity in configuration later on.